# In Dallinger or Psynet an error seems to indicate folder is too large while a proper gitignore file is present

Tags: python

In Dallinger or Psynet an error seems to indicate  folder is too large while a proper `.gitignore` file is present

Error like that shows up:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
✗ 576MB is TOO BIG (greater than 50MB)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because one did not have a git folder in the project.
The solution is to do `git init` and initialize the folder.